# I have a php error log which works correctly, but I'd also like it to show the time the error was "made"

Tags: php, html, datetime, timezone, error-log

So this is my code so far:

```
// Send error message to the server log if error connecting to the database    
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
error_log("Incorrect login details have been entered by a user".PHP_EOL, 3, "logs/ErrorLogs.txt");
```

And it sends it to the error log like this:
[Error log output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVPIN.png)

Before the message "Incorrect login..." I'd like it to show the date and time of the error.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use date()function :

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$errordate = date(DATE_RFC2822); 
error_log("On " .$errordate ." : Incorrect login details have been entered by a user ".PHP_EOL, 3, "logs/ErrorLogs.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the date/time to the string

```
error_log(date('Y-d-m H:i:s') . ": Incorrect login details have been entered by a user" . PHP_EOL, 3, "temp.txt");
```